# Can I block user to choose the same switch case twice in a loop?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have to make a dice game using Scanner.
I will have 3 dice and the user will be asked to choose which one to throw.
The user can't throw all at once - just pick one after another.
It's not allowed to use the same die twice in one round of 3 throws, but user can take the dices in the order user wants.
The game is about to hit a sum of 12.
I have tried to use if statements and switch - but I haven't found a solution for that user can't take same die twice.
I erased some code, but I tried again with switch.

My code is:

// Declaring variables

```
int diceOne = 0;
int diceTwo = 0;
int diceThree = 0;
int rolls;
int rollOne;
int rollTwo;
int rollThree;
int rounds=1;
int sumOfDice =0;


String welcome = "[ Welcome to the game 12! Try to get the total sum of 12 by rolling 1-3 dices ]";
String userInfo = "Enter which dice you want to roll [1,2,3] (Exit game with q): ";


// Create Scanner to obtain data input from user.

Scanner twelf = new Scanner(System.in);

// Welcome message

System.out.print("\n" + welcome + "\n");

// while loop

while(rounds<=3){
System.out.print("\n"+userInfo + " ");
rolls = twelf.nextInt(); 
rounds= rounds + 1; 
rolls =+ rolls;
  

  
switch(rolls){

  case 1:

  diceOne = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
  System.out.print("Dice 1 hits " + diceOne); 

  
  break;


  case 2:
   
    diceTwo = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;  
    System.out.print("Dice 2 hits " + diceTwo);
   break; 

  case 3:
  diceThree = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
    System.out.print("Dice 3 hits " + diceThree);
  break;
  default:  
    
    
}
```

Comment: There seems to be no functional difference between rolling three separate dice or rolling the same dice three times.

Answer (score 0):

It's still a little vague what exactly the program is asking and what the output should be. But it seems that you might need a conditional statement that checks if that certain dice had been rolled already.

```
int diceOne = 0;
        int diceTwo = 0;
        int diceThree = 0;
        int rolls;
        int rollOne;
        int rollTwo;
        int rollThree;
        int rounds = 1;
        int sumOfDice = 0;


        String welcome = "[ Welcome to the game 12! Try to get the total sum of 12 by rolling 1-3 dices ]";
        String userInfo = "Enter which dice you want to roll [1,2,3] (Exit game with q): ";


// Create Scanner to obtain data input from user.

        Scanner twelf = new Scanner(System.in);

// Welcome message

        System.out.println("\n"+welcome +"\n");

// while loop

        while(rounds<=3)

        {
            System.out.print("\n" + userInfo + " ");
            rolls = twelf.nextInt();
            rounds = rounds + 1;
            rolls = +rolls;


            switch (rolls) {

                case 1:
                    if(diceOne > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Cannot roll same dice more than once"); // add a condition that meets your needs to check before rolling the die. //
                    } else {
                        diceOne = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                        System.out.print("Dice 1 hits " + diceOne);


                        break;
                    }


                case 2:
                    if(diceTwo > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Cannot roll same dice more than once"); // add a condition that meets your needs to check before rolling the die. //
                    } else {
                        diceTwo = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                        System.out.print("Dice 2 hits " + diceTwo);
                        break;
                    }

                case 3:
                    if(diceThree > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Cannot roll same dice more than once"); // add a condition that meets your needs to check before rolling the die. //
                    } else {
                        diceThree = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                        System.out.print("Dice 3 hits " + diceThree);
                        break;
                    }
                default:


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using switch statements, you may want to use a map to track if dice were rolled or not. `rolledDiceMap` will store your three dice, it has an `Integer` key and a `Dice` value.

For this I created a `Dice` class that has two fields:

- `value`: the random value that gets rolled);
- `rolled`: boolean flag, if this is true repeat the while loop until the user enters a good value and moves to the next round.

I tried to add some, hopefully, useful comments to the code below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RollDice {
    public static final String WELCOME = "[ Welcome to the game 12! Try to get the total sum of 12 by rolling 1-3 dices ] ";
    public static final String USER_INFO = "Enter which dice you want to roll [1,2,3] (Exit game with q): ";
    public static final String WRONG_DIE_VALUE = "Please enter a good die value";
    public static final String DIE_ROLLED = "Die already rolled, please roll a new die";
    public static final String CONGRATULATIONS = "You rolled 12, congratulations !";
    public static final String GOOD_LUCK = "Good luck next time, your dice rolled: ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rounds = 1;
        int sum = 0;

        // Create Scanner to obtain data input from user.
        Scanner twelf = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(WELCOME);

        Map<Integer, Dice> rolledDiceMap = new HashMap();

        // Generate a key value pair for three dice e.g.: (1, Dice); (2, Dice); (3, Dice)
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            rolledDiceMap.put(i, new Dice());
        }

        while (rounds <= 3) {
            System.out.print(USER_INFO);
            int rolledValue = twelf.nextInt();

            // check if user input is valid (user entered 1,2 or 3)
            if (rolledDiceMap.containsKey(rolledValue)) {
                Dice rolledDie = rolledDiceMap.get(rolledValue);

                // check if die was rolled, if yes, repeat round
                if(rolledDie.wasRolled()){
                    System.out.println(DIE_ROLLED);
                    // repeat round
                    continue;
                }

                // set rolled to true and assign a random value
                rolledDie.setRolled(true);
                int value = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                rolledDie.setValue((int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1);

                sum += value;

                System.out.println("You rolled: " + value);
            } else {
                System.out.println(WRONG_DIE_VALUE);
                // repeat round
                continue;
            }

            // move to next round
            rounds++;
        }

        // print result
        if(sum == 12){
            System.out.println(CONGRATULATIONS);
        } else{
            System.out.println(GOOD_LUCK + sum);
        }
    }

    static class Dice {
        private Integer value;
        private boolean rolled;

        public Integer getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public void setValue(Integer value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public boolean wasRolled() {
            return this.rolled;
        }

        public void setRolled(boolean rolled) {
            this.rolled = rolled;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit for the approach described in comments, without using map:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RollDice {
    public static final String WELCOME = "[ Welcome to the game 12! Try to get the total sum of 12 by rolling 1-3 dices ] ";
    public static final String USER_INFO = "Enter which dice you want to roll [1,2,3] (Exit game with q): ";
    public static final String DICE_ALREADY_ROLLED = "Die already rolled, please roll a new die";
    public static final String ROUND_WON = "You rolled 12, you won the round !";
    public static final String ROUND_LOST = "Rounds lost, your die rolled more than 12. ";
    public static final String ROUND_TIED = "You neither lost, nor won, round tied.";
    public static final String INVALID_INPUT = "Please enter a number between 1-3 or Q to quit";
    public static final String THANKS_FOR_PLAYING = "Quitting game.. thanks for playing!";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int totalRounds = 1;
        int rolledDice, sum = 0;
        int roundsWon = 0, roundsLost = 0, roundsTied = 0;
        int dice1Value, dice2Value, dice3Value;
        boolean dice1Rolled = false, dice2Rolled = false, dice3Rolled = false;

        // Create Scanner to obtain data input from user.
        Scanner twelf = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;

        System.out.println(WELCOME);

        while (true) {
            System.out.print(USER_INFO);
            input = twelf.nextLine();

            // The program should continue until the user chooses to cancel the game. Quit the game by pressing 'q' or 'Q'
            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
                System.out.println(THANKS_FOR_PLAYING);
                break;
            }

            // check if user input is valid
            try{
                rolledDice = Integer.parseInt(input);
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println(INVALID_INPUT);
                continue;
            }

            // The program must randomly find a value on the selected dice and then calculate the score. 
            switch(rolledDice){
                case 1:
                    if(dice1Rolled){
                        System.out.println(DICE_ALREADY_ROLLED);
                        continue;
                    } else{ 
                        dice1Value = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                        sum += dice1Value;
                        dice1Rolled = true;
                        System.out.println("You rolled " + dice1Value + "; sum of dice: " + sum);
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    if(dice2Rolled){
                        System.out.println(DICE_ALREADY_ROLLED);
                        continue;
                    } else{
                        dice2Value = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                        sum += dice2Value;
                        dice2Rolled = true;
                        System.out.println("You rolled " + dice2Value + "; sum of dice: " + sum);
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    if(dice3Rolled){
                        System.out.println(DICE_ALREADY_ROLLED);
                        continue;
                    } else{
                        dice3Value = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                        sum += dice3Value;
                        dice3Rolled = true;
                        System.out.println("You rolled " + dice3Value + "; sum of dice: " + sum);
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    System.out.println(INVALID_INPUT);
                    continue;
            }

            /* The program should also present the number of wins and the number of rounds lost. 
            The definition of profit is when the sum of the dice is 12 (regardless of the number of dice) and 
            the definition of loss is a sum exceeding 12 after all three dice have been rolled. 
            If the sum after three rolls is less than 12, there will be no profit or loss, but you go straight to the next round*/

            // you can move to next round in 2 rounds, by rolling 6 with 2 dice
            if(sum == 12){
                System.out.println(ROUND_WON);
                roundsWon++;
                totalRounds++;

                // reset dice rolled & sum
                dice1Rolled = false;
                dice2Rolled = false; 
                dice3Rolled = false;
                sum = 0;

                // show rounds won/lost/tied
                System.out.println("totalRounds: " + totalRounds + "; roundsWon: " + roundsWon + "; roundsTied: " + roundsTied + "; roundsLost: " + roundsLost);
                continue;
            }

            // If all 3 dice rolled, move to next round
            if(dice1Rolled && dice2Rolled && dice3Rolled){
                if(sum > 12){
                    roundsLost++;
                    System.out.println(ROUND_LOST);
                }
                if(sum < 12){
                    roundsTied++;
                    System.out.println(ROUND_TIED);
                }

                // reset dice rolled, move to next round
                dice1Rolled = false;
                dice2Rolled = false; 
                dice3Rolled = false;
                sum = 0;

                // show rounds won/lost/tied
                System.out.println("totalRounds: " + totalRounds + "; roundsWon: " + roundsWon + "; roundsTied: " + roundsTied + "; roundsLost: " + roundsLost);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your solution :)  I forgot to mention that i can only use logic operators to fix it. it's for a beginner course in Java and we are not at methods yet. :)

Comment: The program must randomly find a value on the selected dice and then calculate the score. The program should also present the number of wins and the number of rounds lost. The program should continue until the user chooses to cancel the game. The definition of profit is when the sum of the dice is 12 (regardless of the number of dice) and the definition of loss is a sum exceeding 12 after all three dice have been rolled. If the sum after three rolls is less than 12, there will be no profit or loss, but you go straight to the next round

Comment: My problem is that if user selects the same option more than once it will still hit the same dice. I'm confused about what loop to use. and also i have to let the user quit by typing q.  so that will mean i have to let the scanner take String and later parse to int? because it's not possible to run a do - while with int and let the user exit with q?

Comment: I edited the post to include the version described in the comments above, without using map

Comment: Thank you  : ) It helped a lot. I didnt use the try catch though :) But i managed to do the assignment as it should :)